# Random Walk on Z

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, random-walk

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$. How do i calculate
$P(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n=\infty)$?
I already know that the probability is 1 but I don't really know how to start? Anyone got some advice? The more basic the better!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use borel cantelli and the central limit theorem combined with the fact that for a normal distributed rv $X$, P(X>c) is positive for any c

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but atm I "haven't got" the CLT yet. I only got Borel-Cantelli/0-1-Law of Kolmogorov. So somehow I should show that $P(\limsup S_n=\infty)>0)$ or resp. that $P(sup_{k\geq n}S_k<M)=0$ for alle M,n, since by the 0-1-Law it is either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_M=[\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n\leqslant M]$ for some fixed integer $M$, then $A_M\subseteq\liminf [S_n\leqslant M]$. Assuming that you know that $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}P[S_n\leqslant M]=\ell$ with $\ell\lt1$ ${}^{(1)}$, this yields $P[A_M]\leqslant\ell$. According to a comment, you also know that $A_M$ is an asymptotic event, hence $P[A_M]=0$. This holds for every $M$ hence $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n=+\infty$ almost surely.

${}^{(1)}$ To show this, proceed by contradiction, then $P[S_n\leqslant M]\to1$ hence $P[S_n\geqslant-M]\to1$ by symmetry, and $P[|S_n|\leqslant M]\to1$. The distribution of $S_n$ is binomial $(\frac12,n)$ hence there exists some absolute finite constant $c$ such that $P[S_n=k]\leqslant c/\sqrt{n}$ for every $k$ and $n$. In particular, $P[|S_n|\leqslant M]\leqslant(2M+1)c/\sqrt{n}\to0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work! I like the solution :)